# Paint the inside of the clipping mask without affecting the other layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections, clipping-mask, painting

I am new to PS and I have no experience with Graphic Design whatsoever.

Here is what I did:

I started with a white background layer. Created a new layer (1) and made a rectangle with the selection tool. I filled it with a gray color. Made a second layer (2) and drew another selection with the lasso tool. I filled it again with a darker color and created a clipping mask from it.

This is the result:

[image]

This is what I tried, while painting only the dark area made from the second layer, while not affecting the light gray area.

[image]

The red lines show, on what layer I tried to paint. I only want the dark area to be affected.

[image]

Edit: Layer Structure

Comment: Can't be certain without seeing the Layers Panel.. but it appears as though you simply need to *reverse* the clipping mask. A black shape on a *mask* means "hide this area".

Comment: I added the Layers Panel.

Comment: You could engage the transparent pixel lock on the dark layer (layer 2). That way, when you paint on it, it will only paint on opaque areas.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work way faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I redid your image and the steps were:

1. Selected the dark gray shape with the Magic Wand tool
2. Created a new empty layer
3. With the new layer active and the selection in place I added a layer Mask
4. The layer Mask is in the shape of the selection
5. I created the red rectangle overlapping the layer mask
6. The light gray background shows through behind the red rectangle.

(The dotted line just shows the extent of the rectangle, it is on an additional layer above everything else.)
[image: Redone original image showing layer mask]

Screenshot of the end result and layers palate

[image: Answer image with Photoshop layers]

Comment: The solution is very similiar, with the solution ChatGPT showed me. And it works and as well as yours. So thanks. But I am not sure, if there is another way. I was watching a chinese tutorial, that uses AI Translation I think, but did without the layer mask. I noticed that he used the selection from layer 2, to make the dark area, and created a new layer, linked it to the clipping mask and started painting, without affecting the other layers. And I didnt understand how, because the Voice Translations was terrible and there is no subtitles.

Comment: There are always at least five different ways to do the same thing in Photoshop! Glad you found more help using different methods.